# Getting could not deserialize exception - Java, PostgreSQL and QueryDSL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Getting a `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize` exception when I call `findAll()` or `findBySn` method.

```
public interface SoaSnRepository extends JpaRepository<SoaSn, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<SoaSn> {
public SoaSn findByZone(Zone zone);
public SoaSn findBySn(Integer sn);
public List<SoaSn> findAll();

}
```

SoaSn class has their attributes:

```
private Integer id;
private Zone zone;
private Integer sn;
```

`Zone` is stored as `bytea` in the table (using `PostgreSQL`)

SoaSn Class:

```
    @Entity
    public class SoaSn extends UpdatedAndCreatedByModel implements Serializable {

        private Integer id;
        private Zone zone;
        private Integer sn;

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "soaSnSeq", sequenceName = "soa_sn_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "soaSnSeq")
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Column(nullable = false)
        public Zone getZone() {
            return zone;
        }

        public void setZone(Zone zone) {
            this.zone = zone;
        }

        @Column(nullable = false)
        public Integer getSn() {
            return sn;
        }

        public void setSn(Integer sn) {
            this.sn = sn;
        }

    }
```

Comment: SoaSn should extend serializable

Comment: @Gaetano implement you meant probably, yes it's doing that

Comment: Yes implement. Zone is not another entity? because check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21463329/2768318

Comment: Zone is an entity but in soa_sn table it's saved as bytea not as FK so I don't think I need to use annotations

Comment: As is written on the answer I think that you have to.

Comment: @Zeromus done, check please.